# Личина и личинка — однокоренные слова?

Tags: словообразование, однокоренные-слова

Интересно, а родственны ли слова **личина** (маска) и **личинка**?
И если да, то хотелось бы понять, какая у них смысловая связь? Вроде ж ничего общего.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос занятный! Я над этим словом никогда не задумывался, но Этимологический словарь Крылова все разъяснил :

> **ЛИЧИНКА**
> Казалось бы, что может быть общего между этим словом, называющим одну из стадий развития насекомого, и словом личина. Говоря "личина", мы имеем в виду внешний вид, за которым скрывается истинная сущность чего-либо или кого-либо. За личинкой скрывается ее истинная сущность: насекомое, которое со временем появится из этой личинки. Образовано с помощью уменьшительного суффикса от личина.

Прекрасная бабочка прячется до поры до времени *под личиною*... *под личинкою*...

Answer (score 1):

Забавно, что у англичан личинки называют *larvae*, и в то же время есть латинское слово *larvæ*, означающее маску/личину, а также привидение.
Словарь этимологии говорит, что в 18-м веке это слово применили для обозначения незрелых форм животных, которые "маскируют" свой взрослый вид (а это, в основном, у насекомых).
Видимо, наши зоологи переняли это обозначение, применив русское лик/личина.